Metric generating a sub-$\sigma$-algebra
It is known that the space $C:=C([0, \infty), \mathbb{R}^d)$ of continuous functions is a complete separable metric space with respect to the metric:
$$
d(f, g) = \sum_{ k = 1 }^{ \infty } ( 1 \wedge \sup_{ 0 \leq s \leq k}|f(s) -g(s)| ) 2^{ - k }, \quad f, g \in C.
$$
Moreover, the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ generated with respect to this metric is given by
$$
\mathcal{F} = \sigma(\{ \pi_s : s \geq 0 \}),
$$
where $\pi_s : C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is the pointwise evaluations at $s$. For every fixed $t \geq 0$ let us now introduce the truncation map
$$
\kappa_t : C \rightarrow C, \quad f(s), s \geq 0 \mapsto f ( s \wedge t), s \geq 0
$$
and denote with $\mathcal{F}_t := \kappa_t^{ -1 } ( \mathcal F)$. It is then straightforward to verify that
$$
\mathcal{F}_t := \sigma(\{ \pi_s : 0 \leq s \leq t \}) \subset \mathcal{F}.
$$
Now I am curious whether for every $t \geq 0$ one can define a metric on $C$ such that the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra with respect to the latter is exactly $\mathcal{F}_t$. At a first naive glance, a possible candidate is
$$
d_t(f, g) = \sum_{ k = 1 }^{ \infty } ( 1 \wedge \sup_{ 0 \leq s \leq k}|f(s \wedge t) -g(s \wedge t )| ) 2^{ - k }, \quad f, g \in C.
$$
However, $d_t ( f, g ) = 0$ does not imply $f=g$, so that $d_t$ is only a pseudometric. On the other hand, is it maybe true that $\mathcal{F}_t$ is generated by the open balls with respect to $d_t$?

If you consider the Borel $\sigma$-algebra w.r.t. a metric, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra necessarily separates points, but $\mathcal{F}_t$ doesn’t, so the best you can hope for is a pseudometric.
